# $(Element).outerWidth() is returning element's DOM instead of width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which outerwidth () returns the selector itself in an array

For `$('.slidePopup').outerWidth()` its returning like this

```
<div class=​"slidePopup">​
   <a href=​"#" class=​"closeSlidePopup">​......</a>​
   <div class=​"sildeInside">​  ​</div>
​</div>​
```

Has someone else faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is an existing bug and fixed in older version.

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12491

Please check whether you are using latest version of jQuery. If not consider upgrading to latest version of jQuery or pass "false" as argument as mentioned in the link

Comment: yeah that is the issue...Thanks :)

Comment: Please set this as answer and up-vote. It will be useful to others.